# Mirror Select2 options without changing selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have two Select2 multi inputs next to each other. One gets it's options immediately populated from an array whilst the other should start off with no available options.

When the user selects some options from the first, I want them to be available to be selected in the second, when removed from the first it should also be removed from the second, ideally removed if selected in the second too.

So far I've managed to get selected options from the first to go to the second, however they way I'm currently doing it means it's automatically "selected" in the second which is not what I want. I just want them as options.

```
$('.secondSelect').select2({ //Start the second select working but blank
    width: '100%'
});

$('.firstSelect').select2({ //Start the first select with data
    width: '100%',
    data: initialData                   
}).on("change", function() { //On a change to the first get the data and re-populate the second select
    var obj = $(".firstSelect").select2("data");
    $(".secondSelect").select2({
        width: '100%',
        data: obj                       
    });    
});
```

Additionally, my attempts to remove the options when the first select2 is changed (setting the second to null on change before re-populating) seems to completely clear the second select2's selected items. Not good.

Hopefully someone can still understand this with all the first's and seconds's flying around! Thanks.

Comment: try this: at the end of your change function add something like $('.secondSelect option').prop('selected', false);

Answer (score 0):

Right, figured it out, sort of.

The array from the first select2 contains `selected: true` which is why they are being "selected" by default. To fix this I'm just running through the array and changing it back to false. The delete problem still persists but it's not too bad.

```
        $('.secondSelect').select2({
            width: '100%'
        });

        $('.firstSelect').select2({
            width: '100%',
            data: initialData                   
        }).on("change", function() {

            var obj = $(".firstSelect").select2("data");                    
       for (var i in obj) {
         if (obj[i].selected == true) {
            obj[i].selected = false;
         }
       }                    
            $(".secondSelect option").remove();
            $(".secondSelect").select2({
                width: '100%',
                data: obj                       
            });   

        });
```

I'm sure theres a better way to do this, but it'll have to do for now.